# Scala string replacement of entire words that comply with a pattern

Tags: string, scala, scala-collections

In a string, how to replace words that start with a given pattern ?

For instance replace each word that starts with `"th"`, with `"123"`,

```
val in = "this is the example, that we think of"
val out = "123 is 123 example, 123 we 123 of"
```

Namely how to replace entire words while preserving the structure of the *sentence* (consider for instance the comma). This won't work, we miss the comma,

```
in.split("\\W+").map(w => if (w.startsWith("th")) "123" else w).mkString(" ")
res: String = 123 is 123 example 123 we 123 of
```

In addition to punctuation marks, the text may include multiple successive blanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`\bth\w*`](http://www.regexr.com/3b6vr) pattern to look for words that begin with `th` followed by other word characters, and then replace all matches with "123"

```
scala> "this is the example, that we think of, anne hathaway".replaceAll("\\bth\\w*", "123")
res0: String = 123 is 123 example, 123 we 123 of, anne hathaway
```

Comment: @dcastro your regex may fail if a word ends with or contains 'th' it needs a word boundary

Answer (score 2):

The above regex in "replaceALL()" might fail if we add "while bathing" in the line, it requires a word boundary as below.

```
  val in = "this is the example, that we think of while bathing"
  out = in.replaceAll("\\bth\\w*", "123")
  out: String = 123 is 123 example, 123 we 123 of while bathing
```

Comment: This produces "123is is 123e example, 123at we 123ink of"

Comment: oh! yes I forgot to read that part. @dcastro your regex is correct +1 for that